# Python: How can i get a list of li tags in BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to scrape a persian webpage and i want to get 3 li tags from a ul containing 6 of them. my problem is that every li, has nested li tags in it and when i use soup.find_all('li'), it finds all of li tags(containing nested ones)

i can't upload the html soup because it's to long for stack overflow

[web page link](http://chap.sch.ir/)

the soup is from this part of webpage:
[image]
it's a government website, so it's probably not updated for 15 years

Comment: You forgot to post the relevant part(s) of your attempt to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try recursion to parse the link tree structure:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_links(ul, path=None):
    if path is None:
        path = []

    for li in ul.find_all('li', recursive=False):
        if li.ul:
            yield from get_links(li.ul, path + [li.a])
        else:
            yield path + [li.a]

url = 'http://chap.sch.ir/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

ul = soup.select_one('#block-taxonomy-menu-block-1 ul')
for links in get_links(ul):
    print('Path: ')
    print(' -> '.join(p.text for p in links))
    print('URLS: ')
    print(' -> '.join(p['href'] for p in links))
    print('-'*80)
```

Prints:

```
...

Path: 
کتاب های درسی استثنایی -> کتاب راهنمای تدریس (راهنمای معلم) -> آمادگی و ابتدایی
URLS: 
/category/%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%87/631 -> /category/%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%87/682 -> /category/%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%87/684
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Path: 
کتاب های درسی استثنایی -> کتاب راهنمای تدریس (راهنمای معلم) -> دوره اول متوسطه پیش حرفه ای
URLS: 
/category/%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%87/631 -> /category/%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%87/682 -> /category/%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%87/685
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Path: 
کتاب های درسی استثنایی -> کتاب راهنمای تدریس (راهنمای معلم) -> دوره دوم متوسطه حرفه ای
URLS: 
/category/%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%87/631 -> /category/%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%87/682 -> /category/%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%87/686
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```